# How do I prove divisibility/primeness given these very large exponentials?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

a) Show that $9^{121} + 13^{1331}$ is divisible by 22 
 b) Show that $30^{239} + 239^{30}$ is not prime

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint for the first part:  an integer is divisible by $22$ if and only if it is divisible by both $2$ and $11$.

Comment: Hint: Both 121 and 1331 are divisible by 11, which suggests using a combination of Fermat's Little Theorem and the Chinese Remainder Theorem. ...

Comment: Part b utilizes Fermat's Little Theorem as well.

Comment: @player3236 Nice! $31=30+1$

Comment: @lulu could you clarify/go a bit more in depth, I still don't really know how to prove it

Comment: Well, what have your tried?  Can you show it is divisible by $2$?  That really shouldn't be hard.  What is $n^{11}\pmod {11}$ for any residue $n$?

Comment: If you like this kind of thing, here's another recent (closed) question involving divisibility of $p^q+q^p$ (like part b of this question) which you may enjoy solving. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3873328/207316

Answer (score 0):

haha, I think we are in the same class. For a) look at $9^{11-1}$ use Fermats, then take that to the 12th power. Then multiply by 9. You should have $9^{121} = 9 (\text{mod }11)$. Then do $13^{11-1}$ with FLT. Take that to the 133th power. multiply by 13, you should get $13^{1331} = 13 (\text{mod }11) = 2 (\text{mod }11)$. Add the two numbers. It's divisible by 11, how do we extend that to 22? Look at $9^{121} (\text{mod }2)$ and $13^{1331} (\text{mod }2)$.

for b I am still working on it.

Comment: To make your answer look better and avoid downvotes, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?).

Comment: QC: `9 \pmod{11}` produces $9\pmod{11}$; use that instead of `\mathrm{mod}` which gives all the wrong spacing.

Comment: FLT says if $p\not\mid a$ then $a^{p-1}\equiv 1\pmod p$ but it *also* says $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$ always.  so $9^{11^2}\equiv (9^{11})^{11}\equiv 9^{11}\equiv 9$. And $1331=11^3$ so $(((13)^{11})^{11})^{11})\equiv ((13)^{11})^{11} \equiv 13^{11} \equiv 13$.  Actually by induction, for any prime $p$ we have $a^{p^k}\equiv a\pmod p$ for all $a$.

Answer (score 0):

A: Using FLT we may write:

$$9^{11}\equiv 9 mod 11$$

$$(9^{11})^{11}=9^{121}\equiv 9^{11} mod 11$$

$$13^{11}\equiv 13 mod 11$$

$$(13^{11})^{121}=13^{1331}\equiv 13^{121}mod 13$$

$$13^{121}\equiv (13^{11})^{11}\equiv 13^{11}\mod 11$$

$$13^{1331}\equiv 13^{11} mod 11$$

$$9^{121}\equiv 9^{11} mod 11$$

$$9^{121}+13^{1331}\equiv (9^{11}+13^{11}) mod 11=11 t +(9^{11}+13^{11})$$

And we can write:

$$9^{11}+13^{11}=(13+9)(13^{10}.11-13^9.11^2+\cdot\cdot\cdot )=22 k$$

Now $9^{121}+13^{1331}$ is even, so is 22, therefore $11 t$ must be even ,so t must be even, hence $11t=22m$ which indicates $9^{121}+13^{1331}$ is divisible by 22.

Conclusion:

If $(a, n)=1$ then $(a^{n^k}, n)=1$ and due to FLT $a^{n^k}\equiv a \mod (n)$.
So we may say:

$9^{121=11^2}+13^{1331=11^3}\equiv (9+13) mod 11$

B:

$30^{239}=(31-1)^{239}=31k-1$

$239^{30}\equiv 1 mod 31=31 m +1$

Therefore:

$30^{239}+239^{30}=31(k+m)$

So it is not prime.

Answer (score 0):

This is cute.

FLT says for a prime $p$ and any $a$ (relative prime or not) that $a^p \equiv a\pmod p$.  So $a^{p^2}=(a^p)^p\equiv a^p \equiv a\pmod p$ and by induction $a^{p^k} \equiv a\pmod p$.

cute.

So $9^{121} + 13^{1331}= 9^{11^2} + 13^{11^3}\equiv 9 + 13 \equiv 22 \equiv 0\pmod {11}$ so $11|9^{121} + 13^{1331}$.

Now we can say $9^{121}$ is odd and $13^{1331}$ is odd so $9^{121} + 13^{1331}$ is even but we are grown-ups now, so we can do grown up proofs. $9^{121} + 13^{1331}\equiv 1^{121}+1^{1331}\equiv 1+1 \equiv 2 \equiv 0 \pmod 2$ so $2|9^{121} + 13^{1331}$.

So $\operatorname{lcm}(2,11) =22$ divides $9^{121} + 13^{1331}$

.... for the second it sames likely we are supposed to do FLT.  $239$ is prime so $30^{239}+239^{30}\equiv 30 + 0\pmod {239}$ that doesn't help much.

But $30 = 31 -1$ and $31$ is prime so

$30^{239} + 239^{30} \equiv (-1)^{239} + 1\pmod {31}\equiv 0 \pmod {31}$ so $31|30^{239} + 239^{30}$.

Kind of cute.  For any prime $p$ and any $a$ so that $p\not \mid a$ we have $(p-1)^a \pm a^{p-1}\equiv 0 \pmod p$  (the $\pm$ is $+$ is $a$ is odd and $-$ if $a$ is even).   Kind of cute